# Unable to plot White Noise graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, whitenoise

I am a beginner, and have written the following code:

```
wn=np.random.normal(loc=raw_data.Quantity.mean(), scale=raw_data.Quantity.std(), size=len(training_data))
training_data['wn']=wn
 training_data.wn.plot(figsize=(20,5), title="LOL")
plt.title('White Noise')
plt.ylim(0,2400)
plt.show()
```

It gives the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

Following are the values for the White Noise:

> *In[140]:wn
>
>   Out[140]: array([313.12254531,  43.56086818, 298.21441411, ...,
>   -50.96308586,
>          193.43057718, 242.80841993])*

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `plot` method on the array itself, try running

```py
plt.plot(wn)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe is because you are trying to get numpy to produce the plot (numpy does not do plotting), whereas it looks like you want to use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for your plotting.

Replace `training_data.wn.plot(figsize=(20,5), title="LOL")` with `plt.plot(wn,'.')` and this will plot each point.

Without more informaiton its difficult to be more specific with the plot. Thie above will plot each point in turn and increment along the x-axis with each point (i.e. if there are 1000 points the x-axis will run from 0-999 with 1 point plotted at each.